# Request method 'POST' not supported in THYMELEAF while editing

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using spring boot, java, and mongodb. I am trying to edit a table row when the button is clicked. My current script allows me to add and delete but I can't edit. It links to my method and displays the value that I am editing but when I click submit, I receive a Request method 'POST' is not supported.

**Controller sample**

```
  //adds values that are inputted in a form
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addServer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveProduct(ApServerModel apServerModel){
    apServerService.saveApServerModel(apServerModel);
    return "redirect:editApServer";
}

//update script in controller
@RequestMapping("editApServer/update/{id}")
public String update(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("server", apServerService.getApServerModelById(id));
    return "update";
}

@RequestMapping("editApServer/new")
public String newServer(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("server", new ApServerModel());
    return "update";
}
```

**HTML sample**

```
    //index.html
        // adding works this works.
        <h2>Add AppPortServer</h2>
        <form action="/addServer" method="POST">
            Host <input type="text" id="host" name="host" /><br />
            Port <input type="text" id="port" name="port" /><br />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>

  //update.html
 //method "post" in here is throwing me an error.
<h2>Server Details</h2>
    <div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${server}" th:action="@{/editApServer}" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Host:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{host}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Port:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{port}"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POST method in your Rest is annotated in the `addServer` path but in the HTML the action of the form method is pointing to `editApServer`.

Change `th:action="@{/editApServer}"` to `th:action="@{/addServer}"`